# Can I use Delphi or C++Builder for Windows Mobile 6.1 Development?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-2009, mobile-devices, c++builder-2009

I'm curious about what it takes to program for mobile devices (Windows Mobile 6.1) and if I can use the IDE's we're already used to (RAD Studio 2009).

Is there a Mobile Development Community around where Delphi or C++Builder users can learn from?

Are there differences in development techniques, like:  Drivers, Memory Limits, Device Specific Considerations and others?

Links to Documentation and Tutorials are always awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do Compact Framework development in Delphi.NET (Prism?) but not natively in 2009.

It was a hot topic in the community a few years ago when I was involved, and it basically came down to resources, cost of implementation and potential license fees that made it not worth doing for Borland (as they were at the time).

That may have changed now, but reading the 2009 feature sheet it appears not...

Edit: It appears there is no designer support for CF in Prism.

Comment: There is no designer in Delphi Prism because MS's designers are tied directly to the C# and VB.NET plugins, and aren't available for any other languages.

You can build CF apps with Delhpi Prism, however.  You just can't design them with the visual designer

Comment: Actually, there was a session at CodeRage III for how to use the WinForms designer to visually build CF Applications with Delphi Prism.  It was pretty cool.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer using Pascal you can use FreePascal to develop for Windows Mobile 6.1